# access dbcontext inside ExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've written an `ExceptionFilter` attribute which in that i need to access `dbContext` class to do database affairs. but i receive `null` reference in my filter attribute.

Is there any way that i can get working reference of `dbContext`?

```
    public class AppExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        AppIdentityDbContext _context;
        public AppExceptionAttribute(AppIdentityDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public AppExceptionAttribute()
        { }

        public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
        {

            var exception = context.Exception;
            while (exception != null)
            {
    //here _context is null, that is a dbContext class
                _context.Errors.Add(new Entities.Error {
                    Message = exception.Message,
                    StackTrace = exception.StackTrace,
                    Date = DateTime.Now
                });

                exception = exception.InnerException;
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

i need to mention that is an asp.net core application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `IServiceProvider` from the `ExceptionContext`.

```
public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
{
    var db = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<AppIdentityDbContext>();

    ...

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much! although method GetService in my case was like that:var db = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(AppIdentityDbContext));

Comment: The generic extension methods `GetService<T>()` and `GetRequiredService<T>()` are in the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace.